# Python imap search only by part of body?

Tags: python, outlook, imap, imaplib

I am using `imaplib` module to connect to outlook account which used for webdriver tests (our application sends emails). Letter contains screenshot and some text.

I am searching inbox following way: `self._imap.search(None, 'UNDELETED', 'UNSEEN', '(TEXT "__some_random_string")')`. Of course, it already connected and logged in. Today I faced strange issue that letter found by `__some_random_strin` or by `__some_random` but is not found by full string. If I opening message in web interface of Outlook then mark it as unread back IMAP search operation completed successfully.

It seems for me that IMAP initially only searches by first N bytes of message or something like that, but I cannot find any mentions about that. Maybe it is feature of IMAP implementation of Outlook.com?

**UPD**: If I am searching using following citeria: `self._imap.search(None, 'UNDELETED', 'UNSEEN')` or `self._imap.search(None, 'UNSEEN')` or `self._imap.search(None, 'UNDELETED')` desired message is found successfully.

Comment: Is this not maybe caused by the `UNSEEN` search filter you've applied?

Comment: @mfitzp I don't think so - initially message has state "UNSEEN" when it is arrives, isn't it?

Comment: That's right but you say "I opening message in web interface of Outlook then mark it as unread back IMAP search operation completed successfully" ...so marking it unread (`UNSEEN`) makes it findable again, correct?

Comment: @mfitzp looks like that.

Comment: But your search `self._imap.search(None, 'UNDELETED', 'UNSEEN', '(TEXT "__some_random_string")')` is filtering *only* on `UNSEEN` messages. If you remove the `UNSEEN` filter in that search you will see the message, no?

Comment: No. If I searching (without opening message in web interface) by `'UNDELETED' 'UNSEEN'` i.e. without string pattern this message found successfully.

Comment: Oh, that is strange. Can you edit question to clarify that a bit? I wonder if this is a search string length limit? i.e. what is the effect of removing `UNDELETED`? Can't find any reference to a limit existing however.

Comment: Updated with my actions.